# Xamarin Android draw Pie chart

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Are there any free API's available for creating Pie Charts in Xamarin Android. If not what other options are available?  Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OxyPlot supports pie chart series, has a PCL core and a Monotouch port

- http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Stuart, did you build it (OxyPlot)? I can't.

Comment: How do I can use OxyPlot in monodroid?

Answer (score 0):

I use ZedGraph extensively in .NET desktop apps, both WinForms and WPF...using C#. It's free and does a nice job on a wide variety of charts, including pie charts.  It's really easy to install and use, here's a link to get you started [Link to SourceForge ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/)

Comment: Did you even check that it runs on Xamarin.Android? Also it seems not to be maintained anymore, last commit was 2009.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about Xamarin, but on the official Android Developers tutorials, there is a sample project containing a PieChart view:

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

I guess you can just take the classes included and repackage them inside your own project.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use Google Charts framework and WebView to display any kind of graphic that you need.

Please, refer to this [**tutorial**](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/08/display-google-charts-pie-chart-on.html) that I've just found.

This is on Android-Java but you can re-code it on Xamarin.Android.